# use jfuzzylite in java program

Tags: java, fuzzy-logic, fuzzy

I start the programming with fuzzy system and recently know that I can use jfuzzylite library in my java program. But I don't know how can use it or call their class to use in my code. Infact, I need implement fuzzofication, rule evaluation, aggregation and deffuzification. So decided use jfuzzylite. But I can't run at least simple example to learn how it can work. Can any one help me?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for your post and choosing jfuzzylite.

To answer your question, you can get started by checking out the example [application on this page](https://github.com/fuzzylite/jfuzzylite/tree/master/examples/application.)

For more visibility on my end, I constantly follow the forums in [fuzzylite](http://www.fuzzylite.com/forums) and try to answer the questions posted there as soon as I possibly can, but there also other members of the community who may be able to help you.

Cheers,

Juan.

Comment: Thanks alot for your pursues. I'll go to your webpage as soon as possible,hope find my answers.